# Does the order of a HClust object give the order in which the labels are appearing on a tree?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm doing WGCNA on expression data and I performed a clustering using the `hclust` function:

```
hierADJ=hclust(as.dist(dissADJ), method="average" )
```

Then I plot this clustering (with some additional color coming from module detection)

```
plotDendroAndColors(hierADJ, colors = colorStaticADJ,
                dendroLabels = FALSE, abHeight = 0.99,
                main = "Gene dendrogram and module colors")
```

See the results in the image below

[image]

My question is: when I have the hclust object  hierADJ, if I do:

```
hierADJ$labels[hierADJ$order]
```

Does it give me the order in which the tips appear (from left to right)? I really need to be sure of that before going further in my analyses

Comment: The answer is yes for the standard dendrogram produced by `plot.hclust`. To be certain, you should run `plotDendroAndColors` with `dendroLabels = TRUE` on a small data set to check. When I did this the order was the same. To be even more confident contact the package maintainer: `maintainer("WGCNA")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a test using part of the `iris` data set to see if the labels match:

```
library(WGCNA)
data(iris)
iris.sub <- iris[c(1:5, 51:55, 101:105), ]
iris.hcl$labels[iris.hcl$order]
# [1] "1"   "5"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "54"  "102" "51"  "53"  "52"  "55"  "103" "101" "104" "105"
clr <- as.numeric(iris.sub$Species) + 1
plotDendroAndColors(iris.hcl, colors=clr)
```

Note that the labels on the plot match the labels listed above.[image: Dendrogram]